# Add compilation symbol for project referenced in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reference, msbuild

I have my project containing most of my functions (MainProject).

I want to have a web service referencing MainProject and use some of those functions.

However I want to add conditionnal compilation in MainProject to not include all the functions and only build them if a webservice project is needing them.

I added one function like this:

```
#if WEBSERVICE
public void MyApi()
{
}
#endif
```

And in the project settings of my web service I tried adding a define constants:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\api\MyAPIs.csproj">
      <Project>{ed6ba855-7082-4b28-99a2-3e9fcf810433}</Project>
      <Name>API</Name>
      <DefineConstants>WEBSERVICE</DefineConstants>
    </ProjectReference>
```

My goal is to add the force the WEBSERVICE symbol to be added when building my web service project.

This doesn't work, when I check the build output my symbol is not added when building the dll for the project.

I know I could add a build configuration to solve that issue but since I will have several webservice projects I would rather keep my build configurations small and just add an extra symbol when needed.

I have also added my WEBSERVICE symbol in each configuration of my Webservice Project

```
<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);SERVICE_BOT</DefineConstants>
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: `DefineConstants` in a `ProjectReference` section doesn't make sense. You can't change the contents of a dll at the place where you consume it. You need to define the symbol when building your api.

Comment: If youonly need a function when a certain project needs it, why not put that function in the project which needs it instead of your main project?